# Ionic 2 and GeoFire

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic2, geofire

I'm looking to add Firebase GeoFire library to my add. Can't seem to import it via the usual methods. Anyone have any success with this?

```
 import * as Geofire from 'geofire';
```

Comment: Did you end up solving this?

Comment: Yeah you just have to add it in a script tag in the index.html and declare let Geofire: any; at the top of your typescipt file right after the imports.. appears to be the only way

Answer (score 1):

Put the following at the top of the page along with your import statements:

`declare var GeoFire: any;`

and then you will have access to the global GeoFire object

`let gf = new GeoFire(ref);`

Comment: Error: Import declaration conflicts with local declaration of 'GeoFire'.